# SQL Server Managed Backup to Azure coexistence with IaaS Backup

Tags: backup, azure, sql

I am devising a backup strategy for a VM running SQL server in Azure.

I wanted to use SQL Server Managed Backup to Azure (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn449496(v=sql.120).aspx) to cover the scenario that someone troubleshooting wants to know what was in one of the DB tables on prod 10 days ago, and can restore the DB from 10 days ago on to a a server in dev.

I wanted to use IaaS Backup (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/backup-azure-arm-vms/) for the more DR type backups, to protect against, say, corruption of the OS files, or a Windows Update that takes down the server.  If we had a DR event I could restore the server from a day or so ago and then use SQL Server Managed Backup to roll the DB forward.

My question is how do these two services interact?  Should I set VSS to copy for SQLIaaSExtension https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/backup-azure-vms-introduction/

This document covers SQL Server Managed Backup to Azure coexistence with various SQL features but is silent on IaaS Backup with SQLIaaSExtension - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn449493(v=sql.120).aspx